# AWS Lightsail site always goes to HTTPS. not HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, bitnami

My AWS Lightsail site, which I've attached a domain to always redirects to an HTTPS:// site rather than an HTTP:// one. I've tried doing a redirect in JS, but it seems to do the redirect at a lower level.

I don't have an SSL certificate yet.
Is there a way to force it to go to HTTP:// for now? It shows a scary *"Go back to safety"* message to visitors

Comment: This isn't a function of AWS Lightsail, it is a function of whatever software you have running on the Lightsail server. Details about that software (is it Apache httpd? nginx? etc.) would be needed to answer your question.

Comment: It’s at te2te.live using Apache, nodejs, and vanilla js

Comment: It sounds like you need to examine your Apache httpd server's config file for HTTPS redirect configuration.

Comment: mmmm. there's a lot in the file, but don't see anything specific to https

Comment: I reset Apach and seemes to be working now...